# ContentLoadingProgressBar is never shows

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I've replaced in my fragment simple `ProgressBar` with `ContentLoadingProgressBar`.
Now fragment layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/simple_match_parent_style">

<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_no_songs"
    android:text="@string/txt_no_songs"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="@style/txt_no_songs"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    style="@style/simple_match_parent_style"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I show this ProgressBar in `onViewCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    progressBar = (ContentLoadingProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progressBar.show();
    ...
}
```

For test purpose I've removed `progressBar.hide()` call to make ProgressBar appear in any case. But the problem is that my `ContentLoadingProgressBar` is never really shown. 
Should I do something else to show `ContentLoadingProgressBar`? I didn't manage to find any relevant examples of using `ContentLoadingProgressBar` so any useful examples are also desirable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may you can find what you are looking for in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438751/example-usage-for-contentloadingprogressbar

Comment: I saw this topic but I didn't find anything useful there

Comment: You cannot use progressBar.show(); here.
after onViewCreated() call, then it's call  ContentLoadingProgressBar.onAttachedToWindow()

look into the source code, they remove show callback here.
So, the progress bar is never shown.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems you need a style, for example...

```
style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

Works for me if I put that anyway, without I never see anything.

Also consider putting it above your content (ie below in the xml)

Comment: It works if you change to this: `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` otherwise there will be the following compilation error: `AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleHorizontal not found.`

Comment: You can now also use a newer style: style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Answer (score 10):

I had tried this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/address_looking_up"
        style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

But, it didn't work at Android 5.0. Some more details about ContentLoadingProgressbar should be here.

PS: Alright, the attribute of 'style' matters here. Change the style to "***?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge***" and it works.

Meanwhile, the display effect of this widget depends on the Theme of your app.

Answer (score 2):

You should add style to ContentLoadingProgressBar.

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.SDK said that “Show the progress view after waiting for a minimum delay. If
      during that time, hide() is called, the view is never made visible.”
2. I think your layout should modify like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/simple_match_parent_style">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_no_songs"
android:text="@string/txt_no_songs"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
style="@style/txt_no_songs"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:divider="@null"
style="@style/simple_match_parent_style"/>
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ContentLoadingProgressBar.onAttachedToWindow()` or `ContentLoadingProgressBar.onDetachedToWindow()` if you are creating multiple views at the same time, it might causing the `private removeCallBacks()` being called in `onAttachedToWindow()` or `onDetachedToWindow()`. Thus causing the runnable to not run, which means nothing will be displayed.

You can, for example:
Simply remove `private removeCallBacks()` calls in `onAttachedToWindow()` or `onDetachedToWindow()`. To prevent this from happening. Don't forget to make `private removeCallBacks()` to `public` and call it in `onDestroyView()` for proper cleanup.